# macOS app goes unresponsive to all button events

Tags: macos, cocoa, events

My app shows strange behavior when I move table view selection too fast. It goes unresponsive, all button stops responding to events. But few things still work in the app. I made a video to explain my problem.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ec96tbf3tpnqqqc/unresponsive.mov?dl=0

I need to know the reason why this is happening. This is not happening when I am debugging the app. It is only happening when I archive the app.

Comment: You have a delayed crash/exception. The error message says that when you clicked one of the button's there is unwrapped nil. Make sure your target has all storyboard/xib/images/frameworks in resulting archived app. Manually compare it (Show package content) to the one you did debugging with.

Comment: Thanks, will work on your advice. Though it occurs at random places in app.